# Using pagination in Eloquent resource throws Undefined Property $id error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-pagination, laravel-resource

I'm trying to build a application in `Laravel 5.7` where I am having a model named `CompanyBehaviour`:

```
protected $table = 'company_behaviour';

protected $guarded= [];

public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Company','company_id','id');
}

public function companyRole()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role', 'company_role_id', 'id');
}

public function companySpecialisation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Noetic\Plugins\Conxn\Models\Variables\Company\Role', 'company_specialisation_id', 'id');
}
```

I'm having a resource file for this:

```
class CompanyBehaviourResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'company' => $this->company->name,
            'company_role' => $this->companyRole->name,
            'company_specialisation' => $this->companySpecialisation->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Which I need to use while fetching the data in my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    return new CompanyBehaviourResource(CompanyBehaviour::whereHas('companies', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20)
    );
}
```

But when I called this I'm getting pagination error:

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$id

And the trace represents that:

```
class: "Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource"
file: "D:\~Resource\CompanyBehaviourResource.php"
function: "__get"
line: 17
type: "->"
```

Stating the `'id' => $this->id,` this line. I've gone through the documentation of [Laravel Resource API](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#pagination) I'm couldn't find where I'm doing wrong. Help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: You need to retrieve your id from request

Comment: @niklaz what do you mean? My request doesn't hold any id, it only holds search string.

Comment: I apologize, I should have looked a bit closer. This means that your eloquent call doesn't return object that holds 'id' property.

Comment: I also had this error. Instead of using a collection , I used a resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call returns eloquent collection, instead of single result, thus not holding `$id` property. 
You should call collection method instead:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    return new CompanyBehaviourResource::collection(CompanyBehaviour::whereHas('companies', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');
    })->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(20)
    );
}
```

Comment: @NitishKumar, try to debug the object, I think that you should use `companies` instead of `company` according to the model that you have provided